# Kotlin reflection: get instance of a member property

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I'm trying to retrieve the instances of my properties, like the example below:

```
data class DataClass(
    val inner: InnerClass
)

data class AnotherDataClass(
    val annotatedProperty: String,
    val dataClass: DataClass
)


instance = AnotherDataClass("prop", DataClass("anotherprop"))

instance::class.memberProperties.forEach {
    // how to retrieve the instance of the properties here?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it in a not-very-beautiful way:

```
instance::class.memberProperties.forEach {
   instance.javaClass.getMethod("get${it.name.capitalize()}").invoke(instance)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `call` here.

```kotlin
import kotlin.reflect.full.memberProperties

data class Member(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
)

fun main(){
    val member = Member(1, "kyakya")
    println(member.id)
    println(member.name)


    member::class.memberProperties.forEach {
        val call = it.call(member)
        println("${it.name} : ${call}")
    }
}
```

Gradle:

```kotlin
plugins {
    // Apply the org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm Plugin to add support for Kotlin.
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.5.0"
}


dependencies {
    // Kotlin
    // Align versions of all Kotlin components
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom"))
    // Use the Kotlin JDK 8 standard library.
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    //
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use kotlin's `kClass` to access the properties. when you are iterating over the properties you can check the type of property and if it is in fact of type `DataClass` then you cast it to `DataClass` and access its values as usual.

```
 var instance = AnotherDataClass("prop", DataClass("AnotherProperty"))
    instance.javaClass.kotlin.memberProperties.forEach{
        var propertyValue = it.get(instance)
        when(propertyValue){
            // if propertyValue is of DataClass then
            // access its internal fields as you like
            is DataClass -> println(propertyValue.inner)
            else -> println(propertyValue)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was trying to do something more generic, I was able to do it :) I'll post the answer here